# Oracle PeopleSoft - Data Mover script taking too much time while database import operation

Tags: peoplesoft

I am using PT859 and PT858 tools and while importing db files data to Database, my VM is taking double the usual time. I am using VM with below configuration:

- Windows Server 2016 Standard
- Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699C v4 @2.20GHz 2.19 GHz
- RAM: 15GB

Please help me guide if any of you have gone through similar problems.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you clarify what the VM is? Is the difference in the DB being on VM vs physical or you local machine is running the Datamover vs a vm running datamover? Is it Oracle or MS SQL db?

Answer (score 0):

Data mover scripts taking longer time to execute have many parameters to look into for it’s better performance.

> Generate the **AWR report** at the time of the script execution and get it
> reviewed with the DBAs. They will suggest you to best actions to be
> taken.
>
> Check the **ASH report** when the script is running .
>
> **ADDM** is self explanatory ,the recommendation are also given along with
> the improvement you would achieve after making the changes

There are general points you could look into, there are many others parameters as well like:

1.Script must be written in the proper manner. Bad scripting causes delay as well.

2.Use the indexes if possible.

3.Check if the database is also slow or it is performing well . If database performance is already low then queries may take longer time.

4.The time you are running your query , check parameters such as Disk I/O, swap utilization, Memory and CPU utilization of the database server, These should not hit the maximum.

5.Generate the execution plan of the query , you will come to know which part of the query is taking longer time. Take action accordingly.

6.Run the script during the off business hours and check how long it takes. If it takes lesser time then there must be load on the database when you are running the scripts .(assuming it’s a production database).